# I can't access the view controllers under the tabbarcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, interface-builder, uitabbarcontroller

I have a tabbarcontroller with 3 subviews.  In IB, I connected 3 navigation controllers to the tabbarcontroller, then I connected to each of the navigation controllers, a tableviewcontroller.  I have public properties that I want to set from the root tabviewcontroller.

My questions are..
1) Is this the correct way to set up the hierarchy?  I heard that you shouldn't embed a tabbarcontroller within a navigation controller, so I made 3 navigation controllers for each tableviewcontroller I needed.

2) The [AITBC description] is null :/

```
NSArray *viewControllers = [self.tabBarController viewControllers];
AllItemTableViewController *AITBC = (AllItemTableViewController *)[viewControllers[0] rootViewController]; //[viewControllers[0] should be the first navigation controller, so I want its root view controller right?
AITBC.AllGroomedItemsArray = self.allGroomedData;
```

Comment: Why does your app need a navigation bar when the user can switch among views with the tabs? Or are you entering the tab bar controller from another view controller?

Comment: @Carpetfizz the entire app is just the 3 tabs.  I want the navigation controller in order to have a nice navigation bar on the top of each tab.  Rather than just being on the bottom.  Is it better/possible to put just a navigation bar on each tableviewcontroller instead of embedding them all in navigation controllers?

Comment: @Carpetfizz  ^^ above

Comment: yeah it is. You can add a `UINavigationBar`. Just set an outlet for it, and you can set its properties as you would normally.

Comment: @Carpetfizz  So is the most prominent reason to use a navigation controller for the back button?

Comment: there's many different uses for it, but in your case, you already have a navigation system, which is your tab bar. And yes, the navigation controller adds a back button. Also, it `pops` or `pushes` views, and doesn't load them when you switch back and forth. So, if you change something in one part of the navigation, and come back to the root, `viewDidLoad:` will not be fired, but `viewWillAppear:` and `viewDidAppear:` will fire,

Comment: @Carpetfizz  Thanks for the explanation!  I'm trying to add the navigation bar to the top of a tableviewcontroller, but it seems it will only let me drop it in the prototype cell.  Do you know how I get it above the cell?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44827/discussion-between-james-and-carpetfizz)

Comment: A navigation controller doesn't have a rootViewController property, you should use topViewController (and you might need to cast viewControllers[0] to a navigation controller).

Comment: You can check my answer below for the summary of what we discussed in chat @James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you cant access your view controllers is because you havent even linked your tabBarController to some sort of code for you to then go on to do some funky stuff.

to link interface builder's tabBarcontroller to your code, simply create your own TabBarViewController class call it something like MyTabBarViewController, and then link that class to your TabBarViewController in your interface builder file.

Once thats done, you will be able to access to your tab bar view controllers from your new class.

Or you can do it via code you could add a tabBarViewController property in your app delegate, and then link the windows.rootViewcontroller to that property to get access to your tabBarViewcontroller in your interface builder without linking anything directly in IB. But you have shown disinterest in having any code in your app delegate as discussed in the conversation chat thread.

you also had `[self.tabBarController viewControllers]` when instead you can do `self.viewControllers` instead.